# Triggering a release with build completion in Azure DevOps Server not working or only happens after hours long delay

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management

We recently migrated an existing team project to a new Azure DevOps Server and find that with our release pipelines, we are seeing that they don't trigger upon a build completion like they did prior to the migration to the new server.  In some cases, we see the releases trigger many hours later (like 14-16 hours later) We're using a continuous deployment trigger subscribed to a build pipeline.  We're using classic build and release pipelines.  Need some help troubleshooting this.  See the images I've attached below.  The build is attached to a github enterprise server repo.  When I manually trigger the release, it grabs the artifact from the build as expected.

[Here is the release pipelines artifact subscription to the build pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/141Av.png)

[Here is the continuous deployment trigger configuration on the release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTB5X.png)

[This shows that the build completed at 11:35 am yesterday - about 16 hours prior to the triggered release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdl8E.png)

[This shows how the release eventually triggered many hours after the build completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rp9i.png)

I expect the release to be triggered directly upon completion of the build to which it is subscripted in the Continuous Deployment Trigger.

Comment: Did you try to re-create a new release pipeline with same definition to see if it can work after the migration? And do other release pipelines migrated from the old server have the same issue?

Comment: yeah we tried that - same result.  All other release pipelines are having the same issue.  We think it could be due to some broken service connections to github on the TFS server causing a big backup because of timeouts in the engine that processes the triggers on the TFS server.  This is a theory at this point, but there are lots of those types of errors in the event log.  That explains why the releases do eventually trigger (after many hours).